# My Spring Boot program restarts even before completing single cycle

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift

While trying to run the Spring Boot application on local, my application works good and ends.

But while trying the same in fabric openshift makes it restart again and again (even before my application 1 cycle end).

Somehow I noticed the difference, **main vs restartedMain**

**In Openshift:**
[image]
Due to which
[image]

**And in Local:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using `spring-boot-devtools` in your project, whenever files change in the classpath, spring-boot-devtools will cause the application to restart.

But it only happens during your development, when you build your class into a jar, and use `java -jar` to launch, spring-boot-devtools will be automatically disabled.